# Cant write a DF as delta table i spark 2.4.4 and scala 2.12 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, delta-lake

Cant write a DF as delta table i spark 2.4.4 and scala 2.12

reading a parquet file as DF
trying to write it as a delta table.

code

```
val dF=spark.read.load("path") //parquet file
dF.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save("path")
```

error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper.$init$(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/module/scala/experimental/ScalaObjectMapper;)V
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.util.JsonUtils$$anon$1.<init>(JsonUtils.scala:27)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.util.JsonUtils$.<init>(JsonUtils.scala:27)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.util.JsonUtils$.<clinit>(JsonUtils.scala)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.metering.DeltaLogging.recordDeltaEvent(DeltaLogging.scala:62)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.metering.DeltaLogging.recordDeltaEvent$(DeltaLogging.scala:56)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaOptions$.recordDeltaEvent(DeltaOptions.scala:133)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaOptions$.verifyOptions(DeltaOptions.scala:176)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaOptions.<init>(DeltaOptions.scala:128)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaOptions.<init>(DeltaOptions.scala:130)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.sources.DeltaDataSource.createRelation(DeltaDataSource.scala:130)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:46)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:131)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:155)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:290)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:229)
  ... 49 elided
```

Kindly help me with this

Answer (score 0):

`Spark 2.4.4` should use `Jackson 2.6.7`.

Check your version. Here is the `pom`: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.4/pom.xml